# Java - Catching Exceptions Using Class Exception

Tags: java

I have to: create a code that demonstrates how various exceptions are caught: using the code template of:

```
catch (Exception exception)
```

Thanks for all of the helpful comments.
I've revised my code:

```
package exception;

import java.util.Scanner;

import java.io.*;
public class Exception
{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
      try
      {
         int a[] = new int[10];
         System.out.println("Access element three :" + a[11]);
         // The reason this is an exception is because there is no element 11 of the array. It only has 10.
      }
      catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e)
      {
         System.out.println("Exception thrown  :" + e);
         // This should print out whatever number was requested for a[e]
      }
      System.out.println("Out of the block");
      // Once the exception is caught, this statement will be printed.
   }
}
```

Output:

```
run:
Exception thrown  :java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 11
Out of the block
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)
```

Now my question is: Is the format done correctly? The problem requires that I use

```
catch (Exception exception).
```

I'm not sure if that's what I did - If not how can I?

Once again, thanks everyone.

Comment: I recommend reading through this first to get familiar with the basic concepts and syntax behind exception handling in Java: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/

Comment: I suggest you not use the `@SuppressWarnings` annotation and that you rename your `class`. Finally, your `main` method probably shouldn't be throwing an `Exception`.

Comment: You should not name your own class `Exception`, the same name as Java's class `java.lang.Exception`. That will cause very confusing error messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the syntax of your try-catch block.
It should be as follows:

```
try {
    //Here goes code that might throw an exception.
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    //Here goes code to handle if an exception was thrown in the try block.
}
```

I'm assuming your assignment hander-outer wants you to not just throw and exception with "throw new java.lang.Exception();" But instead to write some code that might throw an exception.

If you want the code to work the way you're doing it, it'll look like this:

```
try {
    java.lang.Exception exception = new java.lang.Exception();
    throw exception;
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    System.out.println("I caught one!, Here's it's info: ");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

However, if you want to do it the correct way, it'll look something like this:

```
try {
    int number = 500;
    int result = number / 0;
    //This will throw an exception for dividing by zero.

    int[] array = new int[10];
    int bad = array[11];
    //This will throw an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

}
catch(Exception e)
{
    System.out.println("I caught one! Here's some info: ")
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Of course, with the code above, as soon as the first exception is thrown (by dividing by zero), the catch block will catch it and break out of the try block, so the next bad piece of code isn't ever executed.

I recommend looking here for learning what you need to know for this assignment:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/try.html

Also here:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/handling.html

And here as well:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/

Good Luck!

***EDIT***

In your catch block, you can use "System.exit(1);" Which will stop your program and have it return 1, which means that it ended its execution with an error.
However, let's say you're wanting to get a user to enter their age. You can prompt them in a try block and in the case that they enter a negative number, you could catch it with an exception and prompt again until they enter a positive number. In that case, you wouldn't want to use System.exit(1) because then your program would stop when it could keep going, all because a user gave a bad input.

That isn't a good example because you shouldn't handle such trivial things, like negative numbers, with an exception. But the idea is the same. If you want your code to continue on, you'll want to handle the error and continue. The only time to use "System.exit(1);" is if your program can't fix the error given, or if your program only did one task and that task couldn't be completed with the given input or encounters an error in doing that task.

Comment: No problem. To help avoiding other using downvoting your questions, try to make your question more specific. For this question, you could have said, "This is what I tried and it isn't working. Could you help me find the problem?" And even if you can't word it to be more specific, never said you're asking a question that isn't specific. They'll jump all over you if you blatantly say that. Best of luck!

Comment: Good, now you may be concerned because you did not use "catch(Exception e)". But, you actually sort of did, you see ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException is a subclass of Exception. It only catches exceptions that are of that type. If you want to use it, it will still catch the exception for the index out of bounds since that is a subtype of exception so it still of type exception. You can replace your code where you say "catch(ArrayIndex... exception)" with "catch(Exception e)" Then it will catch all exceptions. However, you can have several catch's after a single try to catch/handle different types

Answer (score 0):

This has included some things the other answer forgot, like scriptability (it's a good thing!)

```
package exception;

//import java.util.Scanner; (unused import)
import java.lang.Exception;

public class ExceptionTester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            throw new Exception("Error Message Here");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        };
    }    
}
```